# Google Sheets FILTER formula for range where column is a date?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets worksheet Sheet1 where column E can be either a DATE, e.g. 2018-01-01 or NA or blank.

I want to create another worksheet Sheet2 with only the entries that look like a date, to then be able to create a Data Validation on another worksheet Sheet3 where the date column is only allowed to be entered if it's not already present in the combination of columns B and E in Sheet2.

I assumed I needed to use the `=FILTER()` function but when I try:

```
=FILTER(E:E,ISDATE(E:E))
```

I get:

```
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 18769, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ISDATE won't work because it will return a boolean instead of an array (if all values are dates, it will return true, if even a single one isn't, it will return false).

However, for FILTER you'll need a second array.

I think you could try something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(IF(DATEVALUE(E:E),TRUE),FALSE))
```

And then take it from there with FILTER.

Answer (score 1):

### if this is your Sheet1:

[image]

### ...then all you need to do is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(QUERY(VALUE(Sheet1!E:E), 
 "select Col1 where Col1 > 40000", 0)))
```

[image]